# UIImage from custom UIView in Xib returning empty image with black background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage, nstextattachment

Basically, I'm looking out for a way to attach custom UIView from XIB so that it can be use as link preview in UILabel. I'd choose to convert UIView into UIImage as an image can be use in NSTextAttachment which in turn can use in NSAttributedString.

I'm trying to get image from this UIView. The code is as follows :

```
UIView *preView = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] loadNibNamed:@"LinkPreview" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];

//preView contains 3 labels and 1 imageview with hardcoded values for testing 

if(preView)
{
      preView.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,400,200);
      NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
      attachment.image = [preView snapShot];
      .
      .
}
```

method snapShot is defined in UIView category :

```
#import "UIView+Snapshot.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UIView (Snapshot)

-(UIImage *)snapShot
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.opaque, 0.0f);
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage * snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return snapshotImage;
}

@end
```

This code returning me the empty image with black background.

**Update 1** : The preView is just fine

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Do you see other labels and their texts ?

Comment: No, I can't see that with view's opaque = false, its transparent. But no content visible.

Comment: Firstly check that content is loading or not. Test that by changing the opacity.

Comment: I'm not setting any content. Just debug and test. Please see the attachment in update.

Answer (score 0):

Your view has not been added to view hierarchy. Means that its not rendered yet. Therefore you are getting a black image.

Just for testing purpose, add it as as subview of your current view and then snapshot. It will surely work.

**Update :**

If you need to snapshot without adding it to hierarchy try this

```
-(UIImage *)snapShot
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.opaque, 0.0f);
    [self.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return snapshotImage;
}
```

reference : [Screenshot of a view without displaying it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893318/screenshot-of-a-view-without-displaying-it?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Still not working. The code is running before screen appears. Can this be a cause ?

Comment: Is there any method or third party library to render a view as image before it appear on screen ?

Comment: Just can't do it right now as it may break other things. Will get back once done. Thanks for your time @ibnetariq

Comment: thanks, but its also not working as I tried the same before.